# Prevent empty language versions of items from getting indexed

Tags: indexing, solr, sitecore

We have over 20 languages in our solution and anytime we upload new media or create/edit Sitecore items, the indexing process is slow. Empty language versions of items are getting indexed which are slowing down indexing considerably. Is there a way to prevent empty language versions of items from getting indexed? I am guessing there should be a pipeline that I could tap into and intercept empty items and prevent them from getting indexed.

Also, could there be unintended consequences by preventing empty versions indexing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to filter out the empty items at index time you could try one of these Inbound filter pipeline processors. (This solution only applies to Sitecore 7+ versions though)

http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/sitecore-7-development-team/posts/2013/04/sitecore-7-inbound-and-outbound-filter-pipelines.aspx

Above link is now broken, similar documentation can be found here: https://doc.sitecore.com/SdnArchive/upload/sitecore7/75/sitecore_search_and_indexing_guide_sc75-usletter.pdf

In the processor you could check if the item being indexed has a version in that item's language and update the IsExcluded property to false.

As long as your code to get results from the index can handle it I don't foresee any issues with filtering out the empty items.

Comment: I have edited my question to fix a typo. I am looking for a way to prevent an empty language version of an  item from getting indexed. I have this setting set go true in my instance to get folder items publisbed.

Comment: Ok, I see. No problem. I've updated the answer with a technique I've used in the past to fix a bug with Sitecore and Solr where old versions of items where going into the index. You should be able to use the processor to stop empty items from getting in. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm a little confused about this line - "As long as your code to get results from the index can handle it I don't foresee any issues with filtering out the empty items.". Could you please explain what you mean here?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I just meant if for any reason you might need empty items and you had any code that relied upon it (probably quite a rare scenario)

Comment: I'm checking the index using Luke but I do not see any documents related to empty versions of languages. Does Sitecore index empty language versions or empty items?

Answer (score 2):

Just to follow up and elaborate on the `IsExcludedFromIndex` property, I will provide some examples.  Lets use an example index definition:

```xml
<index id="homepage_nodes_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
    <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
    <param desc="folder">$(id)</param>
    <!-- This initializes index property store. Id has to be set to the index id -->
    <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
    <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
    <!-- NOTE: order of these is controls the execution order -->
        <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/intervalAsyncMaster" />
    </strategies>
    <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
     <!--<crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">-->
     <crawler type="Custom.Webcms.SitecoreUtil.Crawlers.customItemCrawler, Custom.Webcms.Sitecore">
          <Database>master</Database>
          <Root>/sitecore/content</Root>
     </crawler>
</locations>
```

You can see here that the default crawler class has been replaced with a custom crawler class.

You will create the subclass like this:

```cs
public class CustomItemCrawler : SitecoreItemCrawler
```

And override the `IsExcludedFromIndex` property like this:

```cs
protected override bool IsExcludedFromIndex(SitecoreIndexableItem indexable, bool checkLocation = false)
{
    Item obj = (Item)indexable;
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)obj, "item");
    IDocumentBuilderOptions documentOptions = this.DocumentOptions;
    Assert.IsNotNull((object)documentOptions, "DocumentOptions");

    if (!obj.Database.Name.Equals(this.Database, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        Event.RaiseEvent("indexing:excludedfromindex", (object)this.index.Name, (object)obj.Uri);
        return true;
    }
    else if (checkLocation && !this.RootItem.Axes.IsAncestorOf(obj))
    {
        Event.RaiseEvent("indexing:excludedfromindex", (object)this.index.Name, (object)obj.Uri);
        return true;
    }
    else if (...)
    {
        Event.RaiseEvent("indexing:excludedfromindex", (object)this.index.Name, (object)obj.Uri);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (!documentOptions.ExcludedTemplates.Contains(obj.TemplateID.ToString()))
            return false;

        Event.RaiseEvent("indexing:excludedfromindex", (object)this.index.Name, (object)obj.Uri);
        return true;
    }
}
```